# Can't get Label value from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm trying to pass a value from one view controller to another. As i tested this is ok and runs with my code. But i have a problem when i'm trying to take cell label value. I tried everything i found on google and stackoverflow, but there is no answer on this. I added a comment on code which says `// I THINK THE PROBLEM IS ON THE NEXT LINE OF CODE` to help you find where i'm stuck.

**My code:**

```
import UIKit


class PlacesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var placesTableView: UITableView!

var places = [Places]()
var valueToPass:String!
let cellIdentifier = "PlacesTableViewCell"

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.


        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? PlacesTableViewCell  else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of PlacesTableView Cell.")
        }

        let place = places[indexPath.row]

        cell.placeLabel.text = place.name
        cell.ratingControl.rating = place.rating

        return cell

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")


        let indexPath = placesTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

        // I THINK THE PROBLEM IS ON THE NEXT LINE OF CODE
        let currentCell = placesTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as UITableViewCell

        print(currentCell.detailTextLabel?.text ?? "Failed to use Cell Label")
        valueToPass = currentCell.detailTextLabel?.text ?? "Failed to use Cell Label"
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowCommentsTableViewController", sender: self)

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "ShowCommentsTableViewController") {
            // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
            let viewController = segue.destination as! CommentsTableViewController
            // will be stored in passedValue on the CommentsTableViewController
            viewController.passedValue = valueToPass
            //print (viewController.passedValue ?? "")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use the dataSource, not the cell. Also, You are using `PlacesTableViewCell`, not a classic `UITableViewCell`, and you have `placeLabel` as `UILabel`, not `detailTextLabel`.

Comment: You should just use `places` Array to get data, you already have indexPath in didSelect method.

Comment: Tip #1: follow the answer from Scriptable... Tip #2: Don't *"try everything you find on google and stackoverflow"* -- **read and understand** what you find, then implement it. If you don't understand it, slapping in copy/pasted code isn't going to get you anywhere.

Comment: @DonMag Yes you are correct!

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use the raw value from the data store like you do in the cellForRowAt?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let place = places[indexPath.row]
    valueToPass = place.name
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowCommentsTableViewController", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: The suggested edit to my post to change it to `places[(indexPath?.row)!]` I rejected. indexPath is not an optional

Comment: But my compiler said to change that, because it couldn't build. After i made that change, the code is running and it happened what i wanted. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll double check it and update if needed. the function definition above doesn't show optional. Update: is fine in xcode for me

Answer (score 1):

Replace your didselect method with the given below

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{

    let place = places[indexPath.row]

    valueToPass = place.name
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowCommentsTableViewController", sender: self)

}
```

Comment: Thank you! But @Scriptable was first.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic issues in your current code, first you are casting your cell into `UITableViewCell` instead of  `PlacesTableViewCell` and the second issue is that you are accessing `detailTextLabel` which is not available in your custom cell instead of using `placeLabel`. The correct code will be like that:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

{
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")


    let indexPath = placesTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

    // I THINK THE PROBLEM IS ON THE NEXT LINE OF CODE
    let currentCell = placesTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as PlacesTableViewCell

    print(currentCell. placeLabel?.text ?? "Failed to use Cell Label")
    valueToPass = currentCell. placeLabel?.text ?? "Failed to use Cell Label"
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowCommentsTableViewController", sender: self)

}
```

And if you dont want to go through this hassle , you can simply get the values from the original array like that:

```
let place = places[indexPath.row]
valueToPass = place.name
```

Comment: anyone will like to tell me why there is negative vote to my answer?